# what's wrong in my mavenning install netty-socketio-demo?

Tags: maven

I download netty-socketio-demo from github.com, I cannot `mvn install` the server, I got error like

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Users\sun\git\netty-socketio-demo\server\src\main\java\com\corundumstudio\socketio\demo\NamespaceChatLauncher.java:[20,55] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method sendJsonObject(ChatObject)
[ERROR] location: class BroadcastOperations
[ERROR] C:\Users\sun\git\netty-socketio-demo\server\src\main\java\com\corundumstudio\socketio\demo\NamespaceChatLauncher.java:[16,22] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method addJsonObjectListener(Class<ChatObject>,<anonymous DataListener<ChatObject>>)
[ERROR] location: variable chat1namespace which type is SocketIONamespace 
[ERROR] C:\Users\sun\git\netty-socketio-demo\server\src\main\java\com\corundumstudio\socketio\demo\NamespaceChatLauncher.java:[29,55] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] :   METHOD sendJsonObject(ChatObject)
[ERROR] LOCATION: CLASS BroadcastOperations
[ERROR] C:\Users\sun\git\netty-socketio-demo\server\src\main\java\com\corundumstudio\socketio\demo\NamespaceChatLauncher.java:[25,22] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I've found dependencies in my mvn repository. I use command `mvn clean install`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you tried with all the dependencies?

Comment: It's a error in the project, see [this](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio-demo/issues/11)

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne I use the pom.xml shipped with the source. I see both dependencies in that file. Does it need i do any more?

Comment: @Ron check the link that AVolpe has put. It describes how to fix that.

Comment: @AVolpe Your comment is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the [pom.xml](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio-demo/blob/master/server/pom.xml) of the `server` folder:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
   <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
   <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And re run `maven`